# Comparison between RabbitMQ and MSMQ

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, msmq, message-queue

Can I get the comparison between RabbitMQ and MSMQ. It will be helpful performance information on different factors are available.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I wrote a blog post a while back comparing MSMQ and RabbitMQ (among others):

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/message-queue-shootout.html

RabbitMQ gave slightly better performance than MSMQ, but both were comprehensively out performed by ZeroMQ. If performance is your main criteria, you should definitely look at ZeroMQ.

It's worth noting that RabbitMQ and MSMQ are very different beasts. MSMQ is a simple store-and-forward queue. It doesn't provide any messaging patterns, such as pub/sub, or routing. For anything beyond simple point-to-point messaging you'd probably want to use a service bus library such as NServiceBus or MassTransit on top of MSMQ.

RabbitMQ is a sophisticated server product that provides complex messaging patterns, topics and routing out-of-the-box. You also get centralized management and DR, something you'd have to implement yourself if you chose MSMQ.

Comment: Hi! Would you mind to refresh your answer since it was written 3 years ago. Thank you!

Comment: @Dimi you are more than invited to do that.

Comment: What does DR mean?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan Disaster Recovery

Comment: "MSMQ is a simple store-and-forward queue. It doesn't provide any messaging patterns, such as pub/sub, or routing."  This is not accurate.  MSMQ does support multicasting (pub/sub) and offers correlation Id's for identifying unique messages in the same queue.